# Serialize and deserialize ActiveRecord model with children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, deserialization

Form has many entries. To serialize form and it's entries I use:

```
json = @form.to_json( { :only => Form.accessible_attributes.to_a, :include => {:entries => {:only => Entry.accessible_attributes.to_a}}})
```

Form and entries attributes can be modified or deleted while they are in JSON.

To deserialize I use (but not working) :

```
@form = @form.from_json(json)
@form.save
```

How to save entries at once with form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to change entries to entries_attributes:

```
json = @form.to_json( { :only => Form.accessible_attributes.to_a, :include => {:entries => {:only => Entry.accessible_attributes.to_a}}}).gsub('"entries":[{', '"entries_attributes":[{')
```